# Method returning CompletableFuture executes twice when an exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, completable-future

I've got a Spring Boot application which processes messages from an AWS SQS queue. The application makes a request for 10 messages, initiates a `CountDownLatch` to 10, then passes each message to an `@Async` method which returns a `CompletableFuture`.  The `CompletableFuture` has a `thenAccept()` which deletes the message, and a `whenComplete()` which logs an exception if there is one and decrements the latch countdown. When the countdown completes, the next batch of messages is retrieved and the process starts over.
When there is no exception, this all runs perfectly. However, if an exception is thrown within the `CompletableFuture` method, the method executes twice before returning to the `whenComplete()`.

**Main method:**

```
public void readAllMessages(String sqsUrl, MessageConsumer messageConsumer) {
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(sqsUrl).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    List<Message> messages;
    try {
        do {
            messages = amazonSQS.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(messages)) {
                final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(messages.size());
                messages.forEach(message -> {
                    try {
                        messageConsumer.processMessage(message)
                            .thenAccept(m -> {
                                 deleteMessage(sqsUrl, message);
                             })
                             .whenComplete((value, exception) -> {
                                 LOGGER.info("Processing complete for message {}", message.getMessageId());
                                 latch.countDown();
                                 if (exception != null) {
                                     exceptionLogger.logException(String.format("Couldn't process message. queue:%s. id:%s", sqsUrl, message.getMessageId()), exception);
                                 }
                             });
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        LOGGER.error("Refreshing tax rate for message {} failed with exception {} ", message.getBody(), e);
                    }
                });
                latch.await();
            } else {
                LOGGER.debug("Queue is empty: '{}'", sqsUrl);
            }
        } while (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(messages));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Thread interrupted, stopping.");
    }
}
```

**MessageConsumer.processMessage**

```
@XRayLogged(segmentName = "outdated_host_tax_rate_update")
@Async
@Transactional
@Override
public CompletableFuture<?> processMessage(Message message) {
    OutdatedTaxRateMessage taxRateMessage;
    try {
        taxRateMessage = objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody(), OutdatedTaxRateMessage.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Long id = taxRateMessage.getHostId();
    LOGGER.info("Updating tax rate. hostId:'{}', messageId:'{}'", id, message.getMessageId());
    hostTaxRateRefreshingService.refreshHostTaxRate(id);
    LOGGER.info("Updated tax rate. hostId:'{}', messageId:'{}'", id, message.getMessageId());
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

When an exception is thrown, the "Updating tax rate. hostId:''" message is logged twice, followed by a single set of messages from the `whenComplete()` block ("Processing complete...", "Couldn't process message...")

Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but why do you use a latch instead of a simple `CompletableFuture.allOf()`? Also, the code is clearly not sufficient to reproduce the issue, it would be better to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't use `allOf()` because I wasn't aware of it :) Regarding the code, I don't know that I can provide any more of it. It's a Spring Boot app, and this particular chain relies on calls to AWS services, an Async thread pool, and a call to a tax calculation service (where the exception is being thrown). My hope was that someone would recognize this effect in the code that is available here, without having to run it locally. If that's not the case, I think I might be out of luck.

Comment: Writing a [mcve] is a process by which you simplify your problem to the minimum required to reproduce it. For example, the call to AWS is probably not relevant, so you could remove it or mock it. The same probably applies to a lot of your code. In the end, 2 situations are possible: you find the problem on yourself (and ideally post an answer to your own question) or the code has become small enough to post it inside the question. You don't need all the Spring boot boilerplate, but we should be able to compile it and reproduce the problem. And then, it becomes much easier for us to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue was determined to be a custom annotation on the method. The annotation was meant to transmit information to AWS Xray, but was inadvertently executing the annotated method twice when an exception was thrown. That mechanism is still being worked out, but at least we've identified the culprit. The question has been updated, as the annotation had been left off.